# Pillow Fully Transparent Image Black not Transparrent

Tags: python, python-2.7, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a fully transparent image using Pillow in Python

```
img2 = PILImage.new('RGBA', (1920, 1080), (0,0,0,0))
img2.save('test.png')
```

The above code was created referencing:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#constructing-images

`PIL.Image.new(mode, size, color=0)`

color – What color to use for the image. Default is black. If given, this should be a single integer or floating point value for single-band modes, and a tuple for multi-band modes (one value per band). When creating RGB images, you can also use color strings as supported by the ImageColor module. If the color is None, the image is not initialised.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

RGBA (4x8-bit pixels, true color with transparency mask)
The above code generates test.png a black image not a fully transparent image:

System info:

```
$ pip2.7 freeze | grep -i pillow
Pillow==4.0.0

$ python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.9

$ apt list --installed | grep -i imagemagick    
imagemagick/stable,now 8:6.8.9.9-5+deb8u6 amd64 [installed]
imagemagick-6.q16/stable,now 8:6.8.9.9-5+deb8u6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
imagemagick-common/stable,now 8:6.8.

$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-11-26 http://www.imagemagick.org

$ uname -a
Linux revo-vpn-74 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/*release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: Looks to a coding issue as testing the below outside my app the results are as post by Hugo

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me (macOS Sierra / Python 2.7.13 / Pillow 4.0.0) (note the import and `Image.new` instead of `PILImage.new`):

```
from PIL import Image
img2 = Image.new('RGBA', (1920, 1080), (0,0,0,0))
img2.save('test.png')
```

---

### [image: test]

Here's one without transparency:

```
img3 = Image.new('RGB', (1920, 1080), (0,0,0))
img3.save("test3.png")
```

---

### [image: test3]

Comment: It's working for me as well. Note that some image viewers show transparent colors as black. Which image viewer are you using? Do you see the same if you choose a red color (255,0,0,0)? It's also important that you use an image format that supports transparency, but in your example you're using png, so that should be alright.